# How to change the background color only for the current page and next page?

Tags: color, backgrounds

I found that I can change current pagecolor with

`\newpagecolor{color}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}`

so I tried to use

`\newpagecolor{color}\newpagecolor{color}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}`,

that unfortunately changes the color for all pages after this command. Any ideas how to limit this command only to the current and the next page?

Comment: The second `\newpagecolor{color}` after `\newpagecolor` is wrong since the restore color is overwritten with that value, so if the previous colour was `white`, and `\newpagecolor{red}` is used, then `\restorepagecolor` would restore to white, since this is the previous color information. `\newpagecolor{red}\newpagecolor{red}` would first save `white`, but then then 2nd usage would save `red`, so `\restorepagecolor` would restore to red for the rest of the document (or until another `\newpagecolor` is used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the page colour, and then `\restore` it using a nested `\afterpage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pagecolor,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]
\newpagecolor{red}
\afterpage{\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Exactly the same approach can be followed using [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)'s `\pagecolor` command.